# Cron Jobs stopped running

Tags: linux, cron

I have a raspberry pi which has a few cron jobs setup to run some PHP scripts daily at 9pm. I have just checked this morning and for seemingly no reason they have stopped running.

I am using the root user and the cron jobs running the scripts are in /etc/crontab. The only change that I made yesterday was to add some jobs to backup both files and a mysql database to sudo crontab -e, as they were not running when added to /etc/crontab.

Is it possible that this is causing the PHP cron jobs to have stopped for some reason?

crontab -e:

```
# Create Remote Backups
0  0    *   *   *     tar -zcvf /root/orders/backups/daily/files_daily_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    *   *   0     tar -zcvf /root/orders/backups/weekly/files_weekly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    1   *   *     tar -zcvf /root/orders/backups/monthly/files_monthly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    *   *   *     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /root/backups/daily/database_daily_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
0  0    *   *   0     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /root/backups/weekly/database_weekly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
0  0    1   *   *     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /root/backups/monthly/database_monthly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
# Delete Old Remote Backups
0  0    *   *   *     find /root/orders/backups/daily -type f -mtime +3 -
exec rm{} +
0  0    *   *   0     find /root/orders/backups/weekly -type f -mtime +7 -
exec rm{} +
0  0    1   *   *     find /root/orders/backups/monthly -type f -mtime +30 -
exec rm{} +
# Create Local Backups
0  0    *   *   *     tar -zcvf 
/var/backups/ordersystem/daily/files_daily_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    *   *   0     tar -zcvf /var/backups/ordersystem/weekly/files_weekly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    1   *   *     tar -zcvf /var/backups/ordersystem/monthly/files_monthly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.tar.gz /var/www/html
0  0    *   *   *     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /var/backups/ordersystem/database_daily_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
0  0    *   *   0     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /var/backups/ordersystem/database_weekly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
0  0    1   *   *     mysqldump -u root -pPassword wowcher | gzip > /var/backups/ordersystem/monthly/database_monthly_`date +%H-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
# Delete Old Local Backups
0  0    *   *   *     find /var/backups/ordersystem/daily -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm{} +
0  0    *   *   0     find /var/backups/ordersystem/weekly -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm{} +
0  0    1   *   *     find /var/backups/ordersystem/monthly -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm{} +
```

/etc/crontab:

```
# Wowcher Order System
 0    21  *   *   *     root    php /var/www/html/getAttachments.php
 10   21  *   *   0-4   root    php /var/www/html/import.php
```

/etc/crontab also includes all of the same backup commands as in crontab -e ust with the user set to root.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

> ```
> /etc/init.d/cron status
> ```

and if it tells you `cron` is not running (which is most probably true in this case), use

> ```
> /etc/init.d/cron restart
> ```